# How to speed up React building?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

I'm using gulp to compile React JSX to JS, Sass to css and for live reloading. Everything works pretty good but 'building' .js files taking 2.5s-3s. When I tried import React-Bootstrap in my .jsx gulp finished build after 9-10s. Is there any way to speed up building?  Here is my gulp.config:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

function swallowError(error) {
console.log(error.toString())
this.emit('end')
}

gulp.task('build', function() {
    return browserify({ entries: './docs/Main.jsx', extensions: ['.jsx'], debug: true })
        .transform('babelify', { presets: ['es2015', 'react'] })
        .on('error', swallowError)
        .bundle()
        .on('error', swallowError)
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .on('error', swallowError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('docs/dist'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
        .on('error', swallowError);
});



gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {
browserSync.init({
        server: "./docs"
    });
    gulp.watch("docs/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('docs/*.js*', ['build']);
gulp.watch(["docs/*.html"]).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("docs/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .on('error', swallowError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest("docs/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

Comment: [I searched for "gulp build react slow"](https://blog.avisi.nl/2014/04/25/how-to-keep-a-fast-build-with-browserify-and-reactjs/).